# Redirect to another Origin path (Cross-origin) in Node JS route

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node Js route.js when user try to open

app.use('/mysite1', require('express').static(__dirname + '/mysite1'));

then I want to redirect to

app.use('/mysite2', require('express').static(__dirname + '/mysite2'));

Both paths belong to two different origins.

like In the browser user type http://locahhost:5009/mysite1 this URL

but it will open http://locahhost:5011/mysite2 this URL

Comment: `app.use('/mysite1', function(req, res, next){
       res.redirect('http://locahhost:5011/mysite2');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting to a different origin requires nothing special. You just put the URL in the response as normal.

```
res.redirect('http://locahhost:5011/mysite2');
```

Obviously you need to have a route to handle the original URL which runs that code instead of using the static plugin. You aren't serving a static file for the original URL any more.